# Cross Domain API in vNext

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on vNext, and trying to create a web api in asp.net vNext. following are the sample code that i used to create api

```
 public class UserController : Controller
 {

 public IActionResult Get()
 {
 return Result.Json(new { message = "Valid" });
 }

 }
```

I can access this api on browser directly and even i can access this api in same domain view by ajax get request, sample code is below

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 // Get the action URL
 url: "http://mydomainname/api/user",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
 alert(data.message);
 },
 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 alert(errorThrown);
 }
 });
```

But, when i am trying to access this api by means any other domain or jfiddler , it is not working.

check this jfiddler link

http://jsfiddle.net/2r8wj62a/14/

I am using VS2014 CPT.

an i missing anything... any help will appreciated.

Thanks in Advance...!

Answer (score 0):

beta.smallshiptravel.com resolves to ip 74.114.167.68 on my end. Is it the same on your end?

I've tried the link and it is returning:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

So it looks like you are running inside iis and iis returns not found. I would check the iis logs if the request are actually ending up inside your iis server, or if another server (or reverse proxy) is returning the calls. It it does end up in your server then I would add some logging in my code to every request so i could see it my code actually gets called.

HTH,
Bart

Comment: Still a 404, have you checked the iis logs? You can also enable failed request tracing to get some more info (http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85).